# how to format the float to 3 decimal in pinescript

Tags: pivot, version, fibonacci, pine-script

I m using this `alertcondition` to ask the value from a plot, but the returned value has more than 3 decimal places.

Can I format it to make the output only display precision until 3 decimals only?

```
alertcondition(crossover(d2,d3), title="monitor", message='{{ticker}} Monitor If price above Current Price={{close}} PIVOT = {{plot("Pivot")}} SUPPORT = {{plot("S1")}} RESISTANCE = {{plot("R1")}}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you need to format a string to display only three decimal values, then the format string param of the `tostring()` function will help you.

If you need to plot the value with precision of three decimal values, then you might just set the study's param `precision` to 3.

An example of using those params is below:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", precision=3) // precision gives three decimal values in the plot-functions

// the format '#.###' gives three decimal values in a string
val = open / close
s = tostring(val, '#.###') 
label.new(bar_index, high, s)

// this plots only three decimal values, because of the study's param 'precision=3'
plot(val)
```

Answer (score 5):

You will need to round your plotted value:

```
//@version=4
study("")
f_round( _val, _decimals) => 
    // Rounds _val to _decimals places.
    _p = pow(10,_decimals)
    round(abs(_val)*_p)/_p*sign(_val)
plot(close, "CloseP")
plot(f_round(close, 3), "CloseR")
alertcondition(true, "A", 'Unrounded: {{plot("CloseP")}}, Rounded:{{plot("CloseR")}}')
```